# Sum of all numbers in a list at the top level

Tags: scheme, lisp

I'm new to Scheme and I've spent about a week on this.

> Write a Lisp function sumlist which takes a list and returns the sum of all the numbers in the list, at the top level. Thus,
>   **(sumlist '(1 2 (3) (4 a) nil b 5)) should return 1+2+5=8**. The numbers 3 and 4 are not at the top level. Use number? to check if a thing is a number."

This is what I have so far. It can recognize whether something is a number or not, but **I can't get it to only add up the numbers on the top level**.

```
(define (sumlist lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 0)
        ((number? lst) lst)
        ((list? lst)
         (+ (sumlist (car lst)) (sumlist (cdr lst))))
        (#t 0)))
; no values returned
> (sumlist '(1 2 (3) (4 a) nil b 5))
15
```

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Both Jedi's and Daniel's answers work. Thank you both very much.

Comment: You don't need to recurse into `(car lst)` if you only care about the top-level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(define (sumlist lst)
(cond ((null? lst) 0)   ;; list is empty, we're done ;;
   ((number? (car lst)) (+ (car lst) (sumlist (cdr lst)))) ;; the first item is a number, so we add it to the rest
   (else (sumlist (cdr lst))) ;; the first item was not a number, we just check the rest of the list
))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it can be a bit simpler:

```
(define (sumlist lst)
    (cond
        ((null? lst) 0)
        ((number? (car lst)) (+ (car lst) (sumlist (cdr lst))))
        (else (sumlist (cdr lst)))))
```

Since you only care if an element is a number or not, you only have 3 cases.